# how to fetch songs based on multiple conditions from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, exists

I have two tables **songs** and **song_clubs**. The schema is below:-

```
songs schema
 id        available_for      song_name     status
 1           all                 Song 1      1
 2          selection            Song 2      1
 3          selection            Song 3      1
song_clubs schema
song_id     club_id
 2            1
 2            2
 3            2
```

Now i want to fetch the songs of club id **1** and the song is available for all clubs.
My execpted output is like below:-

```
id        available_for      song_name
 1           all                 Song 1
 2          selection            Song 2
```

I have tried below Query

```
select id,available_for,song_name from songs 
 JOIN 
song_clubs
on song_clubs.song_id = songs.id
WHERE songs.status =1 and song_clubs.club_id=1 or songs.available_for ='all'
```

But its only returning one entry that is selection based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.available_for, s.song_name 
FROM songs s
WHERE s.status =1 AND (  
      s.available_for = 'all' 
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM song_clubs c WHERE c.club_id = 1 AND c.song_id = s.id))
```

or with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT id, available_for, song_name 
FROM songs 
WHERE status =1 AND (
      available_for = 'all' 
   OR id IN (SELECT song_id FROM song_clubs WHERE club_id = 1))
```

Comment: first one not working duplicate songs coming

Comment: @kunal bot queries are selecting **only** from `songs`, so there can't be duplicates unless you have duplicates in the table. My queries do not use joins.

Comment: its c.club_id = 1  not   c.id = 1

Comment: which one is faster? join or Exists

Comment: @kunal most of the times EXISTS performs better. But if you expect the subquery of IN to return a few ids of songs only then there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. Use parentheses to group WHERE clauses; otherwise they evaluate left-to-right.
2. Use LEFT JOIN to avoid losing items from your first table that don't match any items in your second table.

This should work (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6dAz91ejhe8AbGECFDihbu/0)

```sql
SELECT id,available_for,song_name 
  FROM songs
  LEFT JOIN song_clubs ON songs.id = song_clubs.song_id
 WHERE songs.status = 1
   AND (song_clubs.club_id=1 or songs.available_for ='all')
 ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this answer too

```
select unique id,available_for,song from songs,song_clubs
WHERE (song_clubs.song_id = songs.id and songs.status = 1 and song_clubs.club_id=1) or (songs.available_for ='all');
```

Here I use full join to select all the matches and then select the unique id values for the songs so you can get only the required 2 rows

[image]

**Note:** It is not the best performance query if you have huge tables.
and it is better to use `EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`.so other answers are more better for performance and this answer is just another way to do that.